# List View display row completely

Tags: android

I have list view with text view in it. I have to make sure that on scrollStop A row is displayed completely or it is not displayed , if the row height is less than 50% of visible area of row(I mean if the row has gone up more than 50%). how is it possible to achieve this...do i need to do animation based on calculating row height or any other method.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use listView.setOnScrollListener() to get the height of the row and do functionality as per your requirement.

[See these links may these help you](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List9.html)